# Converting some C# code to managed or C++/CLI code

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, reflector

I have an existing C# application. What I want is to write native code for some part of the c# application for speed improvement while another part using C# app and the other part using C++/CLI to provide interfaces to C# application. So for latter part, I need to convert C# code into C++/CLI.

I am wondering if I can convert my C# code to C++/CLI code. Maybe converting .net assembly to C++/CLI would be a better idea to get specific code. I looked into reflector and its addin CppCli. But the addin is not available any more. So I am looking for any way to automate this. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Generally speaking you should avoid doing anything except interop in CLI.

Comment: Well, I have written c# code for prototype and we want to improve its speed with c++ application. I wonder if I can automate conversion process.

Comment: You won't improve the speed with C++/CLI (or at least not noticably).  You may improve speed with native C++, but as you are probably aware, that conversion is not trivial.  (We produce a C# to C++ converter, but even with some degree of automatic conversion, it's definitely not for the faint of heart).

Comment: As @DaveDoknjas said C++/CLI really isn't faster.  I do have a project where we improve the speed by interoping with native C++ but it's a LOT of work.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I can understand what you are saying. But I won't move all C# code so it might improve speed. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: May I ask why this question downvoted? No biggie. Just want to know the reason for future reference.

Comment: @david it wasn't me, but I'm going to guess it's because whoever it was thinks it's a bad idea

Comment: I updated my question for clarification

Comment: The correct answer is that a managed assembly is compiled into assembler code by the JIT (Just In Time) compiler at runtime. This is the reason why C# is nearly as fast as C++ and significantly faster than Java. So your question is based on a wrong assumption. It is strange that no answer here mentions the JIT compiler??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking C++/CLI will have about the same run-time as C# (both are managed and probably would be converted to the same IL).  If there is a certain part of your application you need to run faster you can write a C++/CLI layer so your C# app can interop with some native C++.  This will be faster if you write your native C++ appropriately.

EDIT:
As Ben Voigt pointed out, the C++/CLI might be more optimized than the C#, but still not nearly as fast as well-written native C++ since it's still managed.

If you're looking to wrap some native code in C++/CLI then a conversion tool probably wouldn't structure it in a useful fashion anyway.  You're better off just hand-coding the interop portion.

There are [commercial tools](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html) out there that do this, but I think you're still better off doing it by hand.

Comment: I am exactly doing that. I am writing native dll but still need C++/CLI to interface my c# application. For that C++/CLI part, I need conversion. Maybe I had to explain better.

Comment: In some scenarios the C++/CLI compiler produces much more optimized IL than the C# compiler (the C++ team has been writing optimizers for a very long time and have many tricks up their sleeves).

Answer (score 1):

You may not have to convert the code.

link.exe, part of the C++ compiler tools, is able to include both C++ and C# code in the same assembly. The C++ bit can include a mixture of managed and unmanaged code. You first have to compile the C# code to a .netmodule with command line switches of the C# compiler (csc.exe), and then you can use link.exe to compile it into an assembly with C++ code. It's been a while since I've created a mixed language assembly so apologies if the details are not 100%, but search for the above terms and you will find a way to do it.

I seem to remember that the key part is remembering that the C++ compiler is more advanced than the others and so can consume C#/VB netmodules, but not the other way round. I found that the advantage of compiling into a single assembly rather than one referencing another is that types inside each part of the single assembly can cross-reference each other. By having references between two separate assemblies the type awareness relationship has to be hierarchical.

There is also the [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword in C#, which allows C++-ish style pointers to be used within sections of a C# code file, and turns off array bounds checking. There are disadvantages of this that may or may not matter depending on your usage scenario.

Personally I found that running some calculation-intensive code was 20x quicker in the C++ compiler compared to C#, after I had optimised it using the pointers available in C++, which was worth the effort in my case.