# Domain-Specific Language Tools Visual Studio 2012 output C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, dsl, windows-7-x64

I'm new to DSL. I have Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012. I have already installed Visualization and Modeling SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx

Currently, this is outputting C# code. I was wondering if there is anything that I can do to have the code output as C++? Has anyone done this? Do I have to use another tool? or an add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Convert the code from C# to C++/CLI ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411349/converting-some-c-sharp-code-to-managed-or-c-cli-code)),
2. If you're aiming at calling the code from C++, you can build a C++/CLI bridge between the unmanaged code and the managed code.

Comment: I need pure c++ , not C++/CLI. I was just told yesterday, that you can insert the C++ code. I have to figure out how

Comment: I'm selecting this at the answer. It is the closest one.